# Table Locking When using Unions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, union

When multiple selects are used in a `UNION/UNION ALL` are the table locks for each individual `SELECT` statement handled individually or are all table locks held until all `SELECT` statements are completed?

For example, 100 individual select statements are concatenated together via `UNION/UNION ALL`.  (Assuming they are resolved sequentially) If the first `SELECT` in the transaction is completed and another transaction in a different session attempts to access the same data, is the data still locked by the `UNION`?

I am just trying to get an understanding on how `UNIONs` behave with the physical tables while they are still executing.

For the query which prompted this there are 7 different statements in the `UNION` (Not `UNION ALL`).  With this particular question I was just wanting to get an understanding on the back-end architecture of how the `UNION/UNION ALL` worked.  The query which prompted this question causes a lot of blocking but only runs for about a minute, so I was trying to get an understanding on if it was the whole query causing it or just a few of the individual pieces.

I have added a follow-up question here: [Backend Table/Row Locking Structure using CTE Queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224012/backend-table-row-locking-structure-using-cte-queries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `select .. union .. select ..` bits count as a single statement. I can't find an article in the documentation to justify this but I can offer supporting evidence.

First, the semicolon is the [Transact-SQL statement terminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql). There is only one place in your query it will be accepted and that's at the very end of the very last `SELECT`. Second, the execution plan consists of a single tree, indicative of a single statement. In contrast two queries submitted as a single batch would cause two disjoint execution trees.

If there is an explicit [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql) in place the `select..union` becomes part of that and the locks are held until the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. If you have an implicit transaction, by which I mean autocommit, not `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`, it spans all of the selects. Locks will be held for however long they would be held absent the `UNION`, governed by isolation level, query options (`TABLOCKX` etc.), lock escalation, trace flags .. and all the other things that affect this.